# Clone intranet site, but replace content pane with own content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, clone

I'm working at a small company within a rather large company, where I don't really have control over our intranet. I have built a little site/page, and I want it to style exactly like the intranet pages.

I know I can download the stylesheets and start hacking away, but I need the links and the menu's to be up to date.

I'm working with asp.net mvc 2 here, but I've no idea how to go further from here. Thoughts?

Comment: What permissions you have? Can you use iFrame for partial stuff? Is your pages/site will be embedded inside the main site?

Comment: @yytg: I have total control over my own site. And next to nothing on the intranet. Just simple CMS features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to copy the CSS etc.

About the menu - you will need to do the fallowing

use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) for getting the new data, Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing the page, And use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) for getting the relevant data - I will recommend using [caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) for this